# Discord error: [The semaphore timeout period has expired]

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    empty_array = []
    modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="mod-mail")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await modmail_channel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]")

            for file in files:
                await modmail_channel.send(file.url)
        else:
            await modmail_channel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + message.content)

    elif str(message.channel) == "mod-mail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
        member_object = message.mentions[0]
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]")

            for file in files:
                await member_object.send(file.url)
        else:
            index = message.content.index(" ")
            string = message.content
            mod_message = string[index:]
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]" + mod_message)


client.run('My token')
```

Full error traceback:

```
"C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:/Users/Aarav dhanuka/Desktop/Python/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 702, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 812, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 599, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    client.run('ODMyMTkzOTc1MTgyOTUwNDEy.YHgPCQ.CdvekKddU85c8_S7vRzZ_2i33Zc')
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Aarav dhanuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 975, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [The semaphore timeout period has expired]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Showing the errors would be helpful

Comment: What are the errors you get? Those are, quite literally, exactly the lines that show where you did something wrong.

Comment: [Linked Issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159) from github, it has been solved. Please try googling before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is occurring because the wrong token passed through so, maybe regenerate your token and pass a valid one. You can do this by simply going in **https://discord.com/developers/applications** and click one of your applications and go to the bot tab and click the regenerate and copy button:

[image: regenerate or copy button]

Or if you don't have one, then again do the similar thing but this time click on the new application button:

[image: application button]

I hope this will help you, thanks.